# Sublime text, shows a "tab" marker every four spaces, but have the key add 2 spaces

Tags: sublime-text-3

In sublime text as shown there

[image]

are vertical lines every two spaces (my current tab setting), I want Sublime to show a line every four spaces while still only adding two spaces when I press the tab key.

This is because I'm coding in lisp where the indentation is irregular and pressing the tab key for two spaces is the most convenient option (since for special forms and macros I indent only two spaces), but it is preferable to see a line every four spaces because for functions I tend to indent to align all the arguments in one column.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. These lines are placed on tab boundary.

Comment: Can't you leave tab spacing as 4 and use a keyboard macro for two spaces?

Comment: How does one go about implementing a keyboard macro?